# How to Pass an Object to a Formik form in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple Table for students with an Edit button that opens a formik form when clicked with this function:

```
openEditStudentModal = (student) =>{
    
    this.setState({ isEditStudentFromVisible: true });
    EditStudentForm(student)
  }
    

render: (student ) => (
            <Button onClick={() => this.openEditStudentModal(student)}>
              Edit
            </Button>
          ),
```

This is the form that the button opens

```
const inputMargin = { marginBottom: "10px" };
const tagStyle = { backgroundColor: "#f50", color: "white", ...inputMargin };   


const EditStudentForm = (student) => {
 console.log(student)             
    return (
      <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={{
        studentId: "",
        firstName: student.firstName,
        lastName: student.lastName,
        email: "",
        gender: "",
      }}
      
      validate={(values) => {
        const errors = {};

        if (!values.firstName) {
          errors.firstName = "First name required";
        }
        if (!values.lastName) {
          errors.lastName = "Last name required";
        }

        if (!values.email) {
          errors.email = " Email required";
        } else if (
          !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email)
        ) {
          errors.email = "Invalid Email address";
        }

        if (!values.gender) {
          errors.gender = "Gender required";
        } else if (
          !["MALE ", "male", "female", "FEMALE"].includes(values.gender)
        ) {
          errors.gender = "Gender most be ( MALE , male , FEMALE, female )";
        }

        return errors;
      }}
      onSubmit={(student, { setSubmitting }) => {
          editStudent(student).then(() => {
          props.onSuccess();

          setSubmitting(false);
        });
      }}
    >
      {({
        values,

        errors,

        touched,

        handleChange,

        handleBlur,

        handleSubmit,

        isSubmitting,

        submitForm,
        isValid,

        /* and other goodies */
      }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input
            style={inputMargin}
            name="firstName"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.firstName}
            placeholder="First name"
          />

          {errors.firstName && touched.firstName && (
            <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.firstName}</Tag>
          )}
          <Input
            style={inputMargin}
            name="lastName"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.lastName}
            placeholder="Last name"
          />
          {errors.lastName && touched.lastName && (
            <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.lastName}</Tag>
          )}
          <Input
            style={inputMargin}
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.email}
            placeholder="Email"
          />
          {errors.email && touched.email && (
            <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.email}</Tag>
          )}
          <Input
            style={inputMargin}
            name="gender"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.gender}
            placeholder="Gender"
          />
          {errors.gender && touched.gender && (
            <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.gender}</Tag>
          )}

          <Button
            onClick={() => submitForm()}
            type="submit"
            disabled={isSubmitting | (touched && !isValid)}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default EditStudentForm;
```

I want to pass the student to the form so i can use its propertis as the initial Values of the form, the problem tha im getting is that if i console.log(student)  i get two objects ass seen in this picture [image: Example Pic]

and the initial values of the form dont change.